# HTML5 jQuery .animate()({scrollTop: }); not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, html, jquery-animate

I am writing my first HTML5 based app using XDK. I have successfully connected it to a simple local .vb based web service for mock user login validation.  Upon a successful log in I wish to load a new div into the view so that my navigation within the app is consistent in look and feel.

Navigation being performed from the main page works as follows:

```
<ul class="list widget uib_w_3 d-margins" data-uib="app_framework/listview">
  <li class="widget uib_w_4" data-uib="app_framework/listitem">
     <a class="icon user" href="#login_page">Login
     </a>
  </li>
  <li class="widget uib_w_5" data-uib="app_framework/listitem">
    <a class="icon pencil" href="#register_page">Register
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="widget uib_w_6" data-uib="app_framework/listitem">
    <a class="icon settings" href="#settings_page">Settings
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="widget uib_w_7" data-uib="app_framework/listitem">
    <a class="icon paper" href="#acc_management_page">Acc Managment
    </a>
  </li>
  </ul><span class="uib_shim"></span>
```

Everything above works great, and as intended.  Upon clicking/touching the Login button you are taken to the `login_page`, and you have an input field for `username` and `password`.  The login is handled by a jQuery script which verifies the information via a vb.net web service. The login verification is working as intended.  Upon a user entering their `username` and `password` they click the Login button and an onClick event calls the jQuery script which is as follows:

```
function verifyInfo(){
    var uName=document.getElementById("l_username").value;
    var pWord=document.getElementById("l_password").value;           
    $.ajax(  
    {  
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/TestWebService/Verify.asmx/UserVerify',
        data: "{ \"username\":\""+uName+"\",\"password\":\""+pWord+"\"}",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.d == "true"){
                alert("Correct Login Credintials");
            }
            else{
                alert("Incorrect Login Credintials");
            }
            alert(data.d);},
        error: function(data){alert('Failed on :'+data.d);}
    });            
}
```

To achieve the functionality that I want I have added the following piece to this script:

```
function verifyInfo(){
    var uName=document.getElementById("l_username").value;
    var pWord=document.getElementById("l_password").value;           
    $.ajax(  
    {  
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/TestWebService/Verify.asmx/UserVerify',
        data: "{ \"username\":\""+uName+"\",\"password\":\""+pWord+"\"}",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.d = "true"){
                alert("Correct Login Credintials");

                //Added functionality
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#acc_management_page").offset().top
                });
                //End of added functionality

            }
            else{
                alert("Incorrect Login Credintials");
            }
            alert(data.d);},
        error: function(data){alert('Failed on :'+data.d);}
    });            
}
```

This should, if I understand it correctly, fire the animation call to navigate to the appropriate div, in our case `acc_management_page`.  This method of navigation works fine from my navigation menu but is not working from the script.  The login is validated all alerts fire as intended but the acc_management_page is never scrolled to.  Any suggestions and or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is my question to vague or hard to follow? Is there something I can do to improve this question?

Comment: This extremely sample fiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/B4F98/; can you provide an example of your case?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward, I am confused by what you mean in the statement `Can you provide an example of your case?` Thank you for your attempt to help though.

Comment: Note.it should be `data.d == "true"`

Comment: @Himal yessir I fixed that one after the posting, but good catch :).

Comment: What is the result of `console.log( $("#acc_management_page").offset().top );` ? Is that element loaded/ready/in the DOM at all when the animation function is fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try add an "id" attribute to the anchor tag. jQuery is looking for the id not a href.

Comment: I did but ty for checking

Comment: I may have found your problem, the reason why it may not be scrolling is because the page is to small and there is nothing to scroll. I implemented a small fiddle to show you what I mean, when you wrap your HTML up in a wrapper and set a large height value it works.

Also jQuery is looking for the id, not href.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PalinDrome555/2h7Zt/)

Comment: I'll be looking at this today.

Comment: PalinDrome555, I have the following set as the id, `<div class="upage panel" id="acc_management_page" data-header="af-header-4" data-footer="none">`.  I also took your thoughts on adding the `,1000);`. Neither has solved the issue.  I went one step further and moved the animate call to a separate function as you did which would only be called if the login was successful.  I have verified the function is being called on successful login but the animate call is still not occurring.

Comment: Are you getting any errors on your console. Have a look here - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PalinDrome555/2h7Zt/3/).

Comment: Here is the same fiddle with `#wrapper` removed, notice it won't work because nothing is scrollable. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PalinDrome555/2h7Zt/4/)

Comment: Interesting the problem could indeed be due to the fact that the page is not scrollable since this is an html5 based mobile web site / app I would give you a fully copy of the page to look at it but I can't post it in such a... public place.  I will dig further into that being the issue thank you for the tip.

Comment: I believe I have located the issue, and it is related to what you have pointed out.  The page isn't scrollable because the individual pages contained are actually panels.  I.E. mobile frame work swipe panels.  So the real question I should have posted is how to programmatically navigate to a panel.  I will be accepting your answer as you are the one who did lead me to finding the actual issue.  Time to post a new question about panels.  Thank you very much PalinDrome555.

Answer (score 1):

[**LOOK AT THIS Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CristiC777/2wtbLmjf/2/)

Works like a charm :)

```
 $('.uib_w_4').click(function () {
alert('Now I will ask you if your login is ok ! to simulate Login Form');
if (confirm('Login with success !?')) {
    letsAnimate();
} else {
    // Do nothing!
    alert('Login Failed');
};
});
function letsAnimate() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#acc_management_page").offset().top
    });
};
```

Also check your CSS file, if content div is not set properly  (height, position fixed/relative etc) , could generate some unexpected behavior.

[**LOOK AT THIS Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CristiC777/2wtbLmjf/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, but finally I've found the div class that is responsible for scrolling and managed to scrollTop it using css (I've found that XDK scrolling is implemented in the same way - I'm just resetting it to unscrolled params value):

```
$('.afScrollPanel').css('transform', 'matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)');
```